# Set up ckfinder with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckfinder

Are there any connector available for ckfinder with rails ?

How can I setup ckfinder with rails ?

Answer (score -2):

Found [rails-ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor) in github. I've not tried the same. I does not use CKFinder, instead uses [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/).